# What is the use of unsigned char in bitwise negation operation?

Tags: c, unsigned-char, negate

```
unsigned char a = 10,b;
b = ~a;
printf(" %d \n ",b);
```

output:

> 245

same program if I use `int` instead of `unsigned char` the o/p changes to 
`-11`

Answer (score 6):

The variable `a` contains the `unsigned char` value 10.  Assuming an orthodox setup with 8-bit `char` and 32-bit `int` types, then the bits in `a` are:

```
0000 1010
```

The value stored in `b` is the bitwise inverse of what's in `a`, which means it contains the following bits, which correspond to 245 decimal:

```
1111 0101
```

When an `unsigned char` is passed to `printf()`:

```
printf("a = %d\n", a);
printf("b = %d\n", b);
```

the types shorter than `int` (the character types and `short` types — I'm assuming that `short` is a 16-bit type, which is usually but not necessarily the case) are automatically promoted to `int`.  Since the source type is `unsigned char`, the value is converted to a positive `int` value — 10 and 245 in the example code.

Change the type from `unsigned char` to `int` and things alter.

```
a:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1010
b:  1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0101
```

and the bit pattern in `b` corresponds to `-11` because of the way [2's complement arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) (storage) works.  And when these versions of `a` and `b` are passed to `printf()`, there is no conversion necessary, so `printf()` sees `10` and `-11` as the values, and prints accordingly.

The key point is the promotion operation.

In the C standard, it says:

> #### 6.5.2.2 **Function calls**
>
> ¶7 If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does include a prototype,
>   the arguments are implicitly converted, as if by assignment, to the types of the
>   corresponding parameters, taking the type of each parameter to be the unqualified version
>   of its declared type. The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes
>   argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. The default argument
>   promotions are performed on trailing arguments.

Of course, the declared type of `printf()` is:

> ```
> int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);
> ```

So, the values `a` and `b` come after the last declared parameter and are subject to 'default argument promotions'.  They're specified (in part) in paragraph 6:

> ¶6 If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a
>   prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that
>   have type `float` are promoted to `double`. These are called the *default argument
>   promotions*. …

You have to go back a bit further to find *integer promotions*:

> #### 6.3.1 Arithmetic operands
>
> #### 6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters and integers
>
> ¶2 The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned int may
>   be used:
>
> - An object or expression with an integer type (other than `int` or `unsigned int`)
>     whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to the rank of `int` and
>     `unsigned int`.
> - A bit-field of type `_Bool`, `int`, `signed int`, or `unsigned int`.
>
> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a
>   bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned
>   int`. These are called the *integer promotions*.<sup>58)</sup> All other types are unchanged by the
>   integer promotions.
>
> ¶3 The integer promotions preserve value including sign. As discussed earlier, whether a
>   ‘‘plain’’ `char` is treated as signed is implementation-defined.

The concept of rank is defined in §6.3.1.1 ¶1, and I'm not going to quote it (it's fairly long and very detailed).

The key point is that smaller types (like `char`) are promoted to `int`, and preserve the value including the sign.  And what you're seeing exactly matches that.

---

#### Test code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char a1 = 10;
    unsigned char b1 = ~a1;
    printf("a1 = %d, b1 = %d\n", a1, b1);

    int a2 = 10;
    int b2 = ~a2;
    printf("a2 = %d, b2 = %d\n", a2, b2);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a1 = 10, b1 = 245
a2 = 10, b2 = -11
```

Comment: What's important is the integer promotion caused by `~` in itself, because this causes a silent change of signedness. This happens before the printf default argument promotion.

Comment: @FilipKočica: I'm not sure what you did to get 245 printed.  I've added a 'test code' section at the end of my answer showing what I got (on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.6 with GCC 7.1.0, though most machines you try it on will produce the same result anyway).

Comment: Ah sure i thought that you are explaining that `char` to `int` promotion from `8b` to `32b`. My bad.

Answer (score 6):

Whenever `~` is used on an operand of *small integer type*, such as `char`, `unsigned char`, `short` etc, that operand is always implicitly promoted to type `int`. This is known as *the integer promotion rule*.

Meaning that no matter what char type `a` in your example is, it will get promoted to `int` which is a signed type. The expression `~a` is equivalent to `~(int)10`. The result will be (assuming 32 bit CPU) `0xFFFFFFF5`, represented in two's complement as `-11`.

However, when you store this number back into an unsigned char, it will get converted to an unsigned type with value `245`. When you declare `b` as `int`, this conversion doesn't happen and the value remains `-11`.

The above is the reason why `~` is a rather dangerous operator to use. In more complex expressions it can create very subtle bugs caused by the silent change of signedness.

Answer (score 5):

**Unsigned char**

`a`

```
|128|64|32|16|8|4|2|1|
|0  |0 |0 |0 |1|0|1|0|
```

equals `10`

`~` is bit negation

`(unsigned char)~a`

```
|128|64|32|16|8|4|2|1|
|1  |1 |1 |1 |0|1|0|1|
```

equals `245`

Since `8b` `char` is smaller than `32b` `int`, the value is extended to `32b` but the sign is preserved when calling `printf()`.

**Int**

[Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) is `usually` used for signed operations. Let's expect that `sizeof(int)` equals `4B` (`32bit`'s). (Sizeof `int` depend's on architecture.)

`10` in 4B

```
|0|0|0|0| |0|0|0|0| |0|0|0|0| |0|0|0|0| |0|0|0|0| |0|0|0|0| |0|0|0|0| |1|0|1|0|
```

`~10` in 4B

```
|1|1|1|1| |1|1|1|1| |1|1|1|1| |1|1|1|1| |1|1|1|1| |1|1|1|1| |1|1|1|1| |0|1|0|1|
```

To get value in `decimal`

- `~` Negate value
- Add 1
- Change sign

So you have

```
- |0|0|0|0| |0|0|0|0| |0|0|0|0| |0|0|0|0| |0|0|0|0| |0|0|0|0| |0|0|0|0| |1|0|1|1|
```

and it equals `-11` in decimal

> What is the use of unsigned char in bitwise negation operation?

By using `unsigned char` you got `8` bit's `unsigned` which mean's values `0..255`. `(2^8 -1)`

So for `signed char` you've got values `-127..127`.  `(+/-)2^7 -1`

**The unsigned char simply means:** Use the most significant bit instead of treating it as a bit flag for +/- sign when performing arithmetic operations.

Comment: What you are missing to explain is that the `~` doesn't actually work on `unsigned char` type at all, but on `int` type, because of _integer promotion_, which is central to this question. Meaning that the code `if(~a < 0) puts("oops")` will print "oops". Had the op however written something like `int b = (unsigned char)~a;` the result would have remained 245.

Answer (score 0):

`int` variables store `32 bits` and the first bit stands for the sign of number.
If the bit is on, then the number is negative.

the negative numbers are represented as follows:

```
-1 | 11111...111
-2 | 11111...110
-3 | 11111...101
-4 | 11111...100
```

The sequence is almost the same as with positive integers, but in `reversed` order.

Comment: An `int` could be as narrow as 16 bits, or could be wider than 32 bits, according to the Standard.

Comment: Yes, David Bowling, you are right. But I havn't ever met the pc(or compiler) with such standard. I think the majority of all PCs are int - 32 bit, long long - 64 bit.

Comment: Note: The majority of processors made in 2017 are not for PCs.  Billions per year are used in other devices.  [e.g.](https://qz.com/377581/the-chart-that-shows-how-everything-is-becoming-a-computer/)  At least 100s of millions are 16-bit devices.

Answer (score 0):

In C, int and char has to types

1. Signed
2. Unsigned

If user gives int [16 bits] or char [8 bits], then compiler takes by default as signed. for unsigned, Users need to mention explicitly.

unsigned char ranges from 0 to 255 [8 bits].

signed char ranges from -128 to 0 to 127 [8 bits].

As per your program,

Case 1:

a is unsigned char, the output 245 is with in the range of 0 to 255. so you got output as 245.

```
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..................... 254, 255
    |                                          |
    |<- <- <- <- <- <- <- <- <- <- <- <- <- <- |  

    example:
          unsigned char a = 257;       // more than 255.
          printf("a = %d", a);          

         **Output** : a = 1.        // [ 0,1,...255,0 [256th], **1** [257th]

         unsigned char a = 129;       // with in range of 255.
          printf("a = %d", a);          

         **Output** : a = 129.
```

Case 2:

a is signed char, the same output 245 is starting from 0 to 127 and then starts from -128, -127, -126, ..... -11 (245th Position) and prints -11.

```
 -128, -127, -126, ..... -11, -10, .. -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, .....126, 127
   |                                                             |       
   |<- <- <- <- <- <- <- <- <- <- <- <- <- <- <- <- <- <- <- <-<-|

 example:
          char a = 257;          // more than 255.
          printf("a = %d", a);          

         **Output** : a = 1.     // [ 0,1,...127,-128,-127,....-1, 0 [256th], **1** [257th].

          char a = 129;              // with in range of 255.
          printf("a = %d", a);          

         **Output** : a = -127.      // [ 0,1,...127,-128 [128th], **-127** [129th].
```

The same case is applicable for int data type also.